# Unable to save a document into a collection - mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose model for professors which looks like this.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uuidV4 = require('uuid/v4');
var Professors = mongoose.model('Professors', {
    _id:{
        type: String,
        defualt: uuidV4()
    },
    professorfirstName: {
        type: String,
    },
    professroLastName: {
        type: String,
    },
    reviews: [
        {
            review: {
                type: String
            },
            reviewer: {
                type: String
            },
            rating: {
                type: Number
            }
        }
    ],
    ratings: {
        type: Number
    }
}); 

module.exports = {
    Professors: Professors
}
```

My routes for the professors file is as follows:

```
var {Professors} = require('./../server/models/professors');
var {mongoose} = require("./../server/db/mongoose");
var router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/getAllProfessors', (req, res) => {
    Professors.find().then((data) => {
        res.send({data});
    }, (err) => {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
});

router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    var professor = new Professors({
        professorfirstName: "test",
        professorlastName: "test",
        reviews: [],
        ratings: 5
    });

    professor.save().then((data) => {
        res.send({data});
    }, (err) => {
        console.log("Didn't save!!");
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

For the above code, My get route is working fine. I am able to extract all the professors in the database. But my 'add' route is not working. I am not able to to save the record in the collection. I am getting status 400 and I am only getting an empty record in postman like this '{}'. What am I doing wrong in this?

Comment: Try logging `err`: `console.log("Didn't save!!', err)`. By the way, your schema contains some typos (`defualt`, `professroLastName`)

Comment: @robertklep I am getting this error "Error: document must have an _id before saving"

Comment: @robertklep The program is working if I add _id in the add route, but my question is shouldn't uuid provide that Id automatically, since I have added it as default?

Comment: See my answer. Is there a particular reason why you want to use UUIDv4's instead of the default `ObjectId` that's used by MongoDB?

Comment: @robertklep Yes, Professor said so xD. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Haha okay, can't disobey the professor ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your schema:

```
_id:{
    type: String,
    defualt: uuidV4()
},
```

`defualt` is spelled incorrectly, and also, it should reference a function; in your case, you are executing the function immediately and therefore the reference is to a single string, which isn't right.

This should work better:

```
_id : {
    type    : String,
    default : uuidV4
}
```

There's also another typo in the schema: `professroLastName` should be `professorLastName`.